# Getting incorrect values from input file in C

Tags: c, scanf, fopen

I have a few questions involving a program that I'm writing that takes input from a .txt file.

Here's my code so far:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <time.h>

#define NAME_LENGTH 10

void getGrades(FILE *ifp, int assigns, int stus, int grades[assigns][stus]);
void printGrades(int assigns, int stus, int grades[assigns][stus]);
void getStudents(FILE *ifp, int stus, char students[stus][NAME_LENGTH]);
void printStudents(int stus, char students[stus][NAME_LENGTH]);
void calcGrades(int assigns, int stus, int grades[assigns][stus], double final_grades[]);
void printFinalLetterGrades(int stus, double final_grades[]);
void printPercentageGrades(int stus, char students[stus][NAME_LENGTH], double final_grades[]);

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    if (argc != 2)
    {
        printf("Syntax Error: ./<exec> <inFile>\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    
    FILE *ifp = NULL;   

    ifp = fopen("input.txt", "r");
    if (ifp == NULL)
    {
        printf("Could not open %s for reading\n", argv[1]);
        exit(1);
    }

    int assigns = 0;
    int stus = 0;
    
    fscanf(ifp, "%d %d", &assigns, &stus);

    char students[stus][NAME_LENGTH];
    int grades[assigns][stus];
    double final_grades[stus];

    getStudents(ifp, stus, students);
    getGrades(ifp, assigns, stus, grades);
    printStudents(stus, students);
    printGrades(assigns, stus, grades);
    calcGrades(assigns, stus, grades, final_grades);
    printFinalLetterGrades(stus, final_grades);
    printPercentageGrades(stus, students, final_grades);
    
    fclose(ifp);

    return 0;
}

void getGrades(FILE *ifp, int assigns, int stus, int grades[assigns][stus])
{
    int i = 0, j = 0;

    for (i = 0; i < assigns; ++i)
    {
        for (j = 0; j < stus; ++j)
        {
            fscanf(ifp, "%d", &grades[i][j+1]);
        }
    }
}

void printGrades(int assigns, int stus, int grades[assigns][stus])
{
    int i = 0, j = 0;

    for (i = 0; i < assigns; ++i)
    {
        for (j = 0; j < stus; ++j)
        {
            printf("%10d", grades[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}

void getStudents(FILE *ifp, int stus, char students[stus][NAME_LENGTH])
{
    int i = 0;

    for (i = -1; i < stus; ++i)
    {
        fscanf(ifp, "%s", &students[i][NAME_LENGTH]);
    }
}

void printStudents(int stus, char students[stus][NAME_LENGTH])
{
    int i = 0;

    for (i = 0; i < stus; ++i)
    {
        printf("%10s", students[i]);
    }
    printf("\n\n");
}

void calcGrades(int assigns, int stus, int grades[assigns][stus], double final_grades[stus])
{
    int i = 0, j = 0;
    double sum = 0;
    
    for (j = 0; j < stus; ++j)
    {
        sum = 0;
        for (i = 0; i < assigns; ++i)
        {
            sum += grades[i][j];
        }
        
        final_grades[j]= sum / assigns;
    }   
}

void printFinalLetterGrades(int stus, double final_grades[])
{
    int i = 0;

    for (i = 0; i < stus; ++i)
    {
        if (final_grades[i] >= 90)
            printf("         A");
        else if (final_grades[i] >= 80)
            printf("         B" );
        else if (final_grades[i] >= 70)
            printf("         C");
        else if (final_grades[i] >= 60)
            printf("         D");
        else
            printf("         F");
    }
    printf("\n\n\n\n\n");
}

void printPercentageGrades(int stus, char students[stus][NAME_LENGTH], double final_grades[])
{
    int i = 0;

    for (i = 0; i < stus; ++i)
    {
        printf("%10s : %.2lf %%\n", students[i], final_grades[i]);
    }
}
```

and this is the input.txt:

```
8
5
Joel Bob Susan Hillary John
100 92 84 76 68
99 91 83 75 67
98 90 82 74 66
97 89 81 73 65
96 88 80 72 64
95 87 79 71 63
94 86 78 70 62
93 85 77 69 0
```

And here's what I get when I execute the program:

```
      Joel       Bob     Susan   Hillary      John

        16        92        84        76        68
        99        91        83        75        67
        98        90        82        74        66
        97        89        81        73        65
        96        88        80        72        64
        95        87        79        71        63
        94        86        78        70        62
        93        85        77        69         0
         B         B         B         C         F




      Joel : 86.00 %
       Bob : 88.50 %
     Susan : 80.50 %
   Hillary : 72.50 %
      John : 56.88 %
```

Question 1: My getGrades function doesn't correctly give grades[0][0] a new value. When I was debugging it, it seemed like it was just giving it whatever was in that memory position.

Question 2: In getGrades I ineloquently used j+1 in the fscanf statement because it looked like this when it ran if I didn't

```
  Joel       Bob     Susan   Hillary      John

    92        84        76        68        99
    91        83        75        67        98
    90        82        74        66        97
    89        81        73        65        96
    88        80        72        64        95
    87        79        71        63        94
    86        78        70        62        93
    85        77        69         0         0
     B         B         C         F         B
```

The values are all shifted one because it is missing the 100. These problems are probably related? How can I do this part better?

Question 3: In getStudents I put for(i = -1; i < stus; ++i) because otherwise I would get

```
        Joel       Bob     Susan   Hillary

16       100        92        84        76
68        99        91        83        75
67        98        90        82        74
66        97        89        81        73
65        96        88        80        72
64        95        87        79        71
63        94        86        78        70
62        93        85        77        69
 F         A         B         B         C
```

I do notice that 100 appears in this version, but everything else is shifted and I still get the 16 as the first value in the grades.

I'm guessing that I am not accounting for a newline character or have poor logic somewhere. Any clues would be appreciated!

Comment: Ask one question at a time. It is too difficult to answer multiple questions especially as they can lead to different threads. For example, there is no point answering the first question as it would be something like "first undo the things you did for the next two questions".

Comment: This: `for (i = -1; i < stus; ++i)` Why are you starting at `-1` instead of `0`?

Comment: Sorry if I added too many questions, I guessed that those 3 issues were all related and wanted to give all the information since I was stuck. I put for (i = -1; i < stus; ++i) as a bandage fix to make my values align correctly and showed the output on the bottom of the post

Comment: But it's in `getStudents`. So it's reading the first name into `students[-1]`, which is outside the array bounds. This causes undefined behavior.

Comment: You've got some indexing errors. In addition to indexing -1 in the comment above, you also never set a value in grades[0][0] that I can see (John's first score) - you're setting the grades with `fscanf(ifp, "%d", &grades[i][j+1]);` , which I would think overruns your allocation for grades[][].  In C arrays are 0-based, so your first grade would go in grades[0][0], but currently it's going in grades[0][1], and the last grade is likely being written into memory reserved for something else.

Comment: What is `fscanf(ifp, "%s", &students[i][NAME_LENGTH]);` supposed to do? Make it `fscanf(ifp, "%s", students[i]);`.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! So I removed those two issues and that did fix everything except the names were being shifted off by one. I then removed `[NAME_LENGTH]` from `fscanf(ifp, "%s", &students[i][NAME_LENGTH]);` in getStudents and now everything is correct. Was the issue that I was trying to pass to a 2D array when I was only updating one part, the `i`?

Comment: The problem was that reading into `&students[i][NAME_LENGTH]` was reading it into the address directly *after* the name buffer for student `i`. Thus you were reading it into the name buffer for student `i + 1`. You (incorrectly) tried to fix that by starting with index `-1` instead of `0`. But you failed to stop at index `stus - 2` and read the first grade as a student name into an invalid location.

Comment: You should create a [mre] because it seems like you have way more code than needed to reproduce this problem. Also, focus on one problem per question.

Comment: I’ll keep that in mind for future questions, thank you